# Laravel With Sum Function Call to undefined method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

**Laravel 8 with latest updates**

Customer has many machines and machines has many accounts records

**This work {{ machines.accounts }}**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Customer::with([
        'machines',
        'machines.accounts',
        'user'
    ])
        ->get();
});
```

**But withSum() or withCount() doesn't work**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Customer::with([
        'machines',
        'user'
    ])
        ->withSum('machines.accounts', 'credit')
        ->get();
});
```

**Error: Call to undefined method App\Models\Customer::machines.accounts()**

Comment: don't use 2 time `with` and `withSum` use only 1 time `with` or `withSum`

Comment: 2 time with work but when it simple relation like < withSum('accounts', 'credit') >

Comment: i think you need to use call back then

Comment: Call to undefined method App\Models\Customer::machines.accounts()

Comment: the problem is Laravel think it's one relation but it's two it's withSum('machines.accounts', 'credit')

Comment: yes that way i m saying use `with('machines', callback)` use callback and inside add `withSum()`

Comment: Yeah! It's work, Thank you Kamlesh for your time. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using with('machines', callback) and inside add withSum()